# Paint to a bitmap using DirectX under Windows Metro

Tags: directx, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to use DirectX to create and paint into a bitmap, and then later use that bitmap to paint to the screen.  I have the following test code which I have pieced together from a number of sources.  I seem to be able to create the bitmap without errors, and I try and fill it with red.  However, when I use the bitmap to paint to the screen I just get a black rectangle.  Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  Note that this is running as a Windows 8 Metro app, if that makes a difference.

Note that the formatter seems to be removing my angle brackets and I don't how stop it from doing that.  The 'device' variable is of class ID3D11Device, the 'context' variable is ID3D11DeviceContext, the d2dContext variable is ID2D1DeviceContext, the dgixDevice variable is IDXGIDevice, and the 'd2dDevice' is ID2D1Device.

```
void PaintTestBitmap(GRectF& rect)
{
    HRESULT   hr;
    UINT      creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = 
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    ComPtr<ID3D11Device>        device;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
    ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext>  d2dContext;

    hr    = D3D11CreateDevice(  NULL,
                                D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                NULL,
                                creationFlags,
                                featureLevels,
                                ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
                                D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                &device,
                                NULL,
                                &context);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
        device.As(&dxgiDevice);

        // create D2D device context
        ComPtr<ID2D1Device> d2dDevice;
        hr = D2D1CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), NULL, &d2dDevice);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &d2dContext);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                ID2D1Bitmap1 *pBitmap;
                D2D1_SIZE_U  size = { rect.m_width, rect.m_height };
                D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 properties = {{ DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED }, 96, 96, D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET, 0 };

                hr = d2dContext->CreateBitmap(size, (const void *) 0, 0, &properties, &pBitmap);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    d2dContext->SetTarget(pBitmap);
                    d2dContext->BeginDraw();    
                    d2dContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red));     // Clear the bitmap to Red
                    d2dContext->EndDraw();

                    // If I now use pBitmap to paint to the screen, I get a black rectange
                    // rather than the red one I was expecting
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am fairly new to both DirectX and Metro style apps.

Thanks

Comment: looks ok at quick glance. I'd look into bitmap format since I believe that D2D prefers BGRA and how you render to the scree could be affecting your result.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried changing the pixel format to DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (both with and without alpha) but I still get the same result.  Do you know of any examples of how to use DirectX to write to a bitmap?  Thanks

Comment: You could check this sample out: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-basic-image-6b4b1a26 or you could look at other D2D samples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=DirectX&f%5B0%5D.Text=DirectX

Answer (score 0):

what you're probably forgetting is that you dont draw your bitmap on your context.

what you can try is

```
 hr = d2dContext->CreateBitmap(size, (const void *) 0, 0, &properties, &pBitmap);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                ID2D1Image *pImage = nullptr;
                d2dContext->GetTarget(&image);

                d2dContext->SetTarget(pBitmap);
                d2dContext->BeginDraw();    
                d2dContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red));     // Clear the bitmap to Red
                d2dContext->SetTarget(pImage);
                d2dContext->DrawBitmap(pBitmap);
                d2dContext->EndDraw();


            }
```

what you do is store your rendertarget and then draw your bitmap and at the end you set your context to the right render target and let it draw your bitmap on it